# Transaction Notification

Tags: wallet, transaction, script

is there any tool that sends a notification when a incoming transaction happening on your wallet?

Or what is the best way to check it with a script

Answer (score 1):

You want to poll the list transaction endpoint: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/listTransactions

Answer (score 0):

Blockfrost.io has an open source project called [websocket-link](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-websocket-link).